# Is it possible to removeFromSuperview with Animation?

Tags: iphone

I have 2 layer is top and bottom on my program

how can i remove top layer with animation or bring top layer to back is it possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easiest is playing with frame and alpha before removing it.

You can get some cool effects

```
-(void)removeWithEffect:(UIView *)myView
{
 [UIView beginAnimations:@"removeWithEffect" context:nil];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];
 //Change frame parameters, you have to adjust
 myView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
 myView.alpha = 0.0f;
 [UIView commitAnimations];
 [myView performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5f];
}
```

iOS Update

You can now use blocks to perform your animation

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f
     animations:^{view.alpha = 0.0;}
     completion:^(BOOL finished){ [view removeFromSuperview]; }];
```

Comment: when i comment
//[myView removeFromSuperView];

it work.
could you explane me why i must comment that line , 
Xcode tell me UIView may not response removeFromSuperView

Comment: I didn't really test this code, but without the removeFromSuperview the view is only hidden (alpha = 0).

Just put the SuperView 'v' in lowercase : [myView removeFromSuperview];

Comment: thanks santoni 

according to your suggestion to change V to lowercase it work 
but it not have an animation

Comment: tips :
add after beginAnimations,
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1]; // Time in second
I think animation is performed but too quickly

Comment: instead of adding an extra performSelector after the animation you just might set the animation delegate to myview and setAnimationDidEndSelector to @selector(removeFromSuperview) ... this way you can be sure that it is removed as soon as the animation finished.

Answer (score 7):

If you're targetting iOS 4.0 upwards you can use animation blocks:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
     animations:^{view.alpha = 0.0;}
     completion:^(BOOL finished){ [view removeFromSuperview]; }];
```

(above code comes from Apple's UIView documentation)