# removeFromSuperview with animation and views management

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, view, uitabbarcontroller

I did some digging around about this, but nothing really seems to answer my particular question (not even this: [Is it possbile to removeFromSuperview with Animation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714048/is-it-possbile-to-removefromsuperview-with-animation)).

Basically, my app starts with a welcome screen, where a user clicks on "sign in", then goes to the sign in view, then getting to a tab bar view, which is the actual app.

The way I did it, is that I wrote a custom class - TabBarController, which sets up all the tabs and their respective view controllers. Now, when the user clicks on "sign in" i am calling removeFromSuperview and present the tabbar.

I am trying to find a way to animate the transition from the sign in page to the tab bar. I tried some proposed solutions around here, but none seems to do the job. Here is my code in the signin.m view controller. I am looking to animate out the current view (ideally, not just by fading out, but more cool stuff like flips, etc.).

```
//when done signing in --> go to the tab bar view 
-(IBAction)done:(id)sender {

TabBarController  *tabController = [[TabBarController alloc] init];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"removeWithEffect" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:4.0];
self.parentViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
self.parentViewController.view.alpha = 1.0f;
[UIView commitAnimations];
[self.parentViewController.view performSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview) withObject:nil afterDelay:2.5f];
[self presentModalViewController:tabController animated:YES];

}
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That can't work that way. presentModalViewController dislpays the view of a viewController over the own view. It won't replace the source viewController (self).
Since you remove self.parentViewController.view from the view hierarchy, it can't present your tabController modally because you have removed self.

Anyway, i would recommend you another way to achieve your view layout:
Create a tabBarViewController and add its view to a rootView (self.window in the app delegate or whatever you are using now). Then add your login-view to the same view. Due the view hierarchy, the login-view will be displayed above the tabBar.view. And the done button should be implemented this way: (i'm using block syntax for animation as it should be)

```
-(IBAction)done:(id)sender {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 
                     animations:^{
                         self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 480, 320, 480);
                         self.view.alpha = 0.0
                     } 
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){
                         [self.view removeFromSuperView];
                     }
     ];
}
```

You can animate more things than just the alpha, size or position. Just take a look about animations in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html). I guess, you'll be interested in view.transform to commit flip animations. ;)

Comment: +1 Thanks, @Yinkou, this is very helpful. Would you mind showing some code on how to do this: "Create a tabBarViewController and add its view to a rootView (self.window in the app delegate or whatever you are using now). Then add your login-view to the same view." - not sure how to accomplish that. Thanks!

Comment: I'll write you a sample project. just tell me how i can give it to you.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you have to remove the view after animating it.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:2.0];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:myView];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Hope this helps.
Happy coding.

Comment: @TommyG Chk my answer. It could be of some use to u.

Comment: it fades out instantaneously regardless of the duration, and the nav bar remains. plus, i am not sure how to add my next view from here...?

Comment: are u trying to fade it with alpha property of the view ?

Comment: no, i literally copy pasted what you ever you put here, and just added those lines to add my tab bar view, but it doesnt seem to work:  TabBarController  *tabController = [[TabBarController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:tabController animated:YES];

Comment: You can vary the alpha property of the view inside the animation block to produce the fading effect.Try it.