# Will the program throw exception when it runs into the super remove line?

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview

`removeFromSuperview` is a selector of `UIView`. And the superClass of UIView is `UIResponder`, so if The program runs into the code `[super removeFromSuperview]`, the `UIResponder` does not recognise the selector `removeFromSuperView`. So my problem is: will it throw **unrecognized exception**?

```
   - (void)removeFromSuperview
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.35f delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut animations:^{
        self.frame = afterFrame;
        if (self.leftLeave) {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_1_PI / 1.5);
        }else {
            self.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_1_PI / 1.5);
        }
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        [super removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}
```

Comment: This is probably not the right way to do what you want. You might look at something like this instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714048/is-it-possbile-to-removefromsuperview-with-animation

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are writing this code in a subclass of `UIView`, because it seems to be the most likely scenario. As you have probably noticed, it won't throw an exception because `super` is `UIView`, not `UIResponder`.

The class hierarchy is `UIResponder -> UIView -> MyView`.